# d3.nest() Nest array elements with multiple same-level keys (creating duplicates)

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, nested

I'm working with data from the Tate collection published here: https://github.com/tategallery/collection

I'm trying to group the artists by movement. Every JSON object of an artist has a property "movements", which is an array of zero or more elements.

For example, Vito Acconci is associated with Conceptual Art and Performance Art:

```
"movements": [
    {
      "era": {
        "id": 415, 
        "name": "20th century post-1945", 
        "workCount": 3604
      }, 
      "id": 421, 
      "name": "Conceptual Art", 
      "workCount": 478
    }, 
    {
      "era": {
        "id": 415, 
        "name": "20th century post-1945", 
        "workCount": 3604
      }, 
      "id": 436, 
      "name": "Performance Art", 
      "workCount": 81
    }
]
```

I now want to group the artists by their movement, ideally using d3.nest(). My problem is, how do I process artists that are associated with several movements? I'd want them to appear once in every associated movement.

Here is a JSFiddle with an excerpt of the data: http://jsfiddle.net/jwFZV/

Comment: That's the output I want: http://jsfiddle.net/fEyZ6/5/
Can it be optimised?

Comment: There might be a way of implementing this with d3.nest() but I haven't heard of it. You should post your solution as an answer. Thanks for sharing it :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fEyZ6/6/

Figured I actually need a different structure than the one provided by d3.nest(), so this made more sense.

May be a bit more complex than necessary, but I needed to be able to restructure by string property or an array of objects. I'm using an identifier to pick an object property as array key. Considered using a map, but I'm changing the objects, so keys would't match.

Optimisation suggestions still welcome.

```
var Hierarchy = function(data, accessor) {

    var data = data,
        accessor = accessor,
        identifier = "name",
        hierarchy = false,
        rebuild = false;

    this.hierarchy = function() {

        if(hierarchy && !rebuild) {
            return hierarchy;
        }

        hierarchy = [];
        var keys = [];

        if( !accessor) {
            console.log("ERROR no accessor for hierarchy");
            return false;
        }


        for (var i in data) {

            var parents = accessor.call(data, data[i]);

            if( Object.prototype.toString.call( parents ) != "[object Array]") {

                parents = [parents];

            };

            parents.forEach( function(element) {

                if(typeof element === "object") {

                    p = keys[element[identifier]];

                } else {

                    p = keys[element];

                }

                if (!p) {

                    p = {
                        element: element,
                        children: []
                    };
                }

                p.children.push(data[i]);


                if(typeof element === "object") {

                    keys[element[identifier]] = p;

                } else {

                    keys[element] = p;

                }

            } )


        }

        for (var i in keys) {

            if( typeof keys[i].element != "object" ) {
                keys[i].element = {
                    name: keys[i].element
                }
            }

            keys[i].element.children = keys[i].children;
            hierarchy.push(keys[i].element);

        }

        rebuild = false;

        return hierarchy;
    }

    // accessors
    this.data = function(_) {
        if(!arguments.length) return data;
        data = _;
        rebuild = true;
    };

    this.identifier = function(_) {
        if(!arguments.length) return identifier;
        identifier = _;
        rebuild = true;
    };

    this.accessor = function(_) {
        if(!arguments.length) return accessor;
        accessor = _;
        rebuild = true;
    };


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is pretty much already nested, that's the problem.

Check out the example at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_pairs (after d3.pairs).

The example starts out with a flat data set of three similar objects and after it's nested the objects are duplicated to belong to several groups at the same time. This is far more versatile  than a pre-nested JSON object because the objects are referenced instead of created as new.

In your data set, movements are duplicated to be under multiple artists, but if two artists have the same movement, you can't compare them using ==. It will always return false.

Another approach would to send each object collection (artists, movements...) as it's own flat array of objects. The objects can show their relationship to other objects by some key property, or a list of indexes of their related objects.

The table approach would also allow you to send your data to the client as CSV or TSV. If you're dealing with a huge data set, you know how much space object keys take up, and they're the same for each object! A table header solves that problem. This becomes a lot more noticeable when dealing with integers and short string values.

To start, you should get rid of duplicate objects and separate out the different data types. This will give you a much cleaner starting point.

Here are a couple pistol shaped snippets to start. They work on

```
var artists = data;

var movements = data.reduce(function(object, artist){
  artist.movements = artist.movements.map(function(movement){
    object[movement.id] = object[movement.id] || movement;
    return movement.id;
  }).join(',');
  return object;
},{});

var eras = d3.values(movements).reduce(function(object, movement){
  var eid = movement.era.id;
  object[eid] = object[eid] || movement.era;
  movement.era = eid;
  return object;
},{});
```

Comment: Very valid points, thanks! I assume the original dataset is indeed a set of relational tables, but they chose to expose it as JSON objects of artists.

Comment: That is usually the case, in fact, that's pretty much the purpose of a public facing web app. To store object relationships and render a pretty website so when a user asks it something. However if it's outputting JSON, then it really should do it in a manner that makes sense to JSON consumers, and not attempt to pretty up the data by faking object relationships.